# CGContextClip Antialiasing issue

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I am drawing a shape in a UIView drawRect function that involves clipping a path, and then adding coloured blocks behind so that the colors have the shape of the clipped path. However, for some reason the lines of the path are not coming out smoothly; its if the antialiasing isn't working properly.

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
CGContextBeginPath (context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xStart, yStart);
for (int i=0; i<points.count; i++) {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xPoint, yPoint);
    }

}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xStart, yStart );
CGContextClip(context);

CGRect colorRect = CGRectMake(0, 0 , rectWidth, rectHeight);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, blockColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, colorRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The result should have smooth lines, but it comes out jagged with visible pixels as in this image:

[image: Image of the jagged line]

Any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are drawing a histogram, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, its a histogram

Answer (score 0):

Okey. So, there is no problem in your code. The problem is that antialiasing works a little different. You drawing a vertical slopes expecting that edge of resulting histogram will be smoothed. But actually antialiasing doesn't smooth the resulting figure. It works with path elements (curves, lines) one by one. So, for example if you draw a circle, its edges will be smoothed.

There is a simple solution of your problem: just create a curve, enveloping the histogram. Add it to your context. It will look more smooth.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'll explore this but you are wrong about how the chart is composed... those aren't bars or vertical slopes, they should be lines but are rendering like bars on the pixel boundaries

Comment: Ok, anyway, they are separate lines. How many points do you have in the array?